# pip is installing packages globally instead in virtual environment in windows

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, package, virtualenv

I had created a project in pycharm using virtualenv environment.

My current location is 
`(venv) C:\Users\username\Documents\pycode\MyProj1>`

Now I am running pip install flask and it is downloading packages in the global environment,i.e., `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages` instead of my virtual environment.

I can install packages in the virtual environment only when I go to project interpreter in settings and then adding flask.

Can anyone tell how can I install packages in virtual environment by using pip?

Comment: You need to activate your virtual environment, and then use `pip` to install packages.

Comment: Virtual environment is already activated as my terminal points to `(venv)`. I had again tried to activate the virtual environment and then used `pip` to install packages but same problem persists.

Comment: `python -m pip install package` downloads the package in virtual environment while `pip install package` downloads the package in global environment.

Comment: I have the same problem on Debian, `(venv) $ python -m pip install xyz` is globally installed (after disable the venv I check with `$ python -m pip list` and `xyz` is also there!)

Answer (score 0):

In your Command Prompt enter:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Launch virtualenv
In your Command Prompt navigate to your project:

```
cd your_project
```

Within your project:

```
virtualenv env
```

Activate your virtualenv:

on Windows, virtualenv creates a batch file

```
\env\Scripts\activate.bat
```

to activate virtualenv on Windows, activate script is in the Scripts folder :

```
\path\to\env\Scripts\activate
```

Example:

```
C:\Users\'Username'\venv\Scripts\activate.bat
```